# How can I move multiple objects towards a central point in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I want to move a set of objects towards a central point. 
Think moving objects that are outlining a circle towards the middle. 
I know you can do this through the bounding box, but that results in the objects being resized and I don't want them resized.

The effect that I have in mind is like the Symbol Scruncher tool except that I want to move the objects at a specific distance.

I also won't be able to use the Scruncher because I didn't spray my symbols randomly.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to move a group of all objects to a center pint, without resizing them, **you'll have to do it manually** or in specific groups (left, top objects - right, bottom objects, etc).

**There is no method to concentrate objects around a given point without resizing.**

Scripting may be able to do this. But I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

1. Turn each object independently into a symbol.
2. Select them all (the bounding box
3. Re-size them all together so they are closer to the center
   point (as you indicated, each object will get re-sized)
4. With all the symbols still selected, right click and select "Reset Transformation". The symbols will recover their original size but stay in the new spot.

Answer (score 0):

How about bounding box and then offset path to restore the size?

Comment: Would you mind fleshing out your answer a little more to add some clarity for people who don't know how to do that?